# What is meant by the notation $\tau_1\prec\tau_2?$

Tags: notation

Let $\tau_1,\tau_2$ be two topologies on a set $X.$ What is meant by the notation $\tau_1\prec\tau_2?$ Does it simply mean $\tau_1\subset\tau_2?$

Comment: I believe it varies from author to author and requires definition, although it might vary from field to field instead. I know it is sometimes used as an arbitrary ordering relation between elements in a set.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Sets can be [partially ordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) according to the relation

$$A \preccurlyeq B \Leftrightarrow A \subseteq B$$